# Creating Static ( Like ) Variables - Best Practice

Tags: javascript

Every time I need a static variable, I end up tacking it on as a property to the object that uses it and needs it to persist.

Particularly, this index here(`MT.MAOrb.startR.index`) I need to be static or hold it's value until the function is called again by a callback.

Is using this form the best way to do this?

`MT.MAOrb.startR.index`

```
/**
 ** MAOrb
 */


MT.MAOrb =
{
    pre : function() {
        var o_p = {
            model : 'MAOrb'
            };
        return o_p;
    },
    post : function( o_p ) {
        MT.MAOrb.startR( o_p );
    },
    startR: function( o_p ){
        var sky = document.getElementById( 'Ab1' );
        if( MT.MAOrb.startR.index === undefined ) {
            var size = Object.size( o_p );  
            console.log( 'size' + size );
            var index1 = MT.MAOrb.random( 0, size - 1 );
            console.log( 'index1' + index1 );
            MT.MAOrb.startR.index = index1;
            MT.MAOrb.startR.o_p = o_p;
        }else{ 
            MT.MAOrb.startR.index++; 
        }
        var image_element = MT.MAOrb.makeElement( MT.MAOrb.startR.o_p[ MT.MAOrb.startR.index ] );
        sky.appendChild( image_element );
        MT.MAOrb.moveLinear( image_element );
    },// ....more code here
};
```

Comment: This is called memoization. And it's good for you, when used correctly.

Comment: Nifty word...originated from AI studies in the 60's...reference->http://addyosmani.com/blog/faster-javascript-memoization/

Comment: I think you're both a little confused; I don't see any memoization in this code at all.  Memoization (as I understand it) involves replacing a function with a new version of itself, where the new version has a "shortcut" to save calculation.  I see no function replacement here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to emulate a public static property, then that's a totally A-OK way to do it.

JavaScript is not a classical object oriented language. It is prototypical.

One ramification is that there really isn't a concept of static in the language.

The way you're doing it is totally fine, as long as you don't mind that another object can directly read and modify the property.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has no concept of static vs. non-static variables: everything is just a property of an object.  As such, there is no right or wrong way of doing static variables, only right or wrong ways of doing static-like variables.

That being said, adding the variable as a property of a fixed (module-like) object, as you're doing, is pretty much your best bet (ie. best practice).  Unless you're using a library like Backbone.js that is, which actually does add support for static variables to its "models" (ie. it's class system).

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that it's actually a rather strange way to do it. Javascript provides function level scope, and you can use that to your advantage by using an immediately-invoked-function-expression (IIFE):

```
myObject = {
    count: (function () {  // this function is invoked immediately
        var staticCounter = 0;
        return function () { // this is the actual 'count' function
            return ++staticCounter;
        };
    }())
};

myObject.count(); // 1
myObject.count(); // 2
```

One reason that this could be considered a better approach is that it completely hides the static variable. If you were to do `myObject.count.staticCounter`, some other code *might* be reading or writing to that variable. Obviously you wouldn't want that to happen, but if you do this, you are completely guaranteed of that variable's scope, which leads to easier debugging and refactoring in the future.

Comment: What memory does your IIFE use...I have had a hard time understanding what it "pulls in" so I avoid IIFE's out of this misunderstanding.

Comment: No real problem. It defines a function and executes it immediately. Nothing holds a reference to that function itself (though its scope is preserved), so it is not held in memory. It's a very common pattern in Javascript these days.

Comment: but...what is the trade-off between the ( execution time and possible extra memory utilization ) vs. adding in privacy ( a core OO concept )...

Comment: Nothing holds a reference to which function?

Comment: "Nothing holds a reference to which function?" - the IIFE, the outer function. The execution time is **completely** negligible. The memory usage would be identical: one extra variable, stored either in scope or on the function object.

Comment: A book reference to IIFE...Crockford?

Comment: No, I mean, the IIFE is a function expression which is not stored anywhere. That means that a function (the outer one) is created and then executed, and then it is not referenced by anything so the garbage collector can remove it. It just happens to return a new function and THAT one is store to the value of `myObject.count`: exact same memory requirements.

Comment: IIFE *(first result in Google, btw)*: http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Comment: Usually I just read web stuff ...but his has been confusing me for a while...so I head to the books.  I'll check it out though..thanks...and nice web site.